# use tensorflow to model sentence similarity

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am trying to model sentence similarity use tensorflow. The ideal is that first feed the concatenated sentence to a rnn, then feed the output of the rnn to a softmax to do a binary classification, similar or not. I make some minus changes to the [PTB language model example](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/tutorials/recurrent/index.html#recurrent-neural-networks) , but the cost won't decrease as expected.

```
cost: 0.694479 
cost: 0.695012
cost: 0.6955
...
```

The code is as follows. Any kind of help would be appreciated.

```
class PTBModel(object):
"""The PTB model."""
def __init__(self, is_training, config):
    self.batch_size = batch_size = config.batch_size
    self.num_steps = num_steps = config.num_steps
    size = config.hidden_size
    vocab_size = config.vocab_size
    label_size = 2
    self._input_data = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [batch_size, num_steps], name="inputs")
    # for each sentence pair we only have one output
    self._targets = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, [batch_size], name="labels")
    # Slightly better results can be obtained with forget gate biases
    # initialized to 1 but the hyperparameters of the model would need to be
    # different than reported in the paper.
    lstm_cell = rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(size, forget_bias=0.0)
    if is_training and config.keep_prob < 1:
        lstm_cell = rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(
                lstm_cell, output_keep_prob=config.keep_prob)
    cell = rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([lstm_cell] * config.num_layers)
    self._initial_state = cell.zero_state(batch_size, tf.float32)
    with tf.device("/cpu:0"):
        embedding = tf.get_variable("embedding", [vocab_size, size])
        inputs = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embedding, self._input_data)
    if is_training and config.keep_prob < 1:
        inputs = tf.nn.dropout(inputs, config.keep_prob)
    # Simplified version of tensorflow.models.rnn.rnn.py's rnn().
    # This builds an unrolled LSTM for tutorial purposes only.
    # In general, use the rnn() or state_saving_rnn() from rnn.py.
    #
    # The alternative version of the code below is:
    #
    # from tensorflow.models.rnn import rnn
    # inputs = [tf.squeeze(input_, [1])
    #           for input_ in tf.split(1, num_steps, inputs)]
    # outputs, states = rnn.rnn(cell, inputs, initial_state=self._initial_state)
    outputs = []
    states = []
    state = self._initial_state
    with tf.variable_scope("RNN"):
        for time_step in range(num_steps):
            if time_step > 0: tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()
            (cell_output, state) = cell(inputs[:, time_step, :], state)
            outputs.append(cell_output)
            states.append(state)

    # use the output of the last word as the input feature to softmax
    output = tf.reshape(tf.concat(1, outputs[-1]), [-1, size])
    softmax_w = tf.get_variable("softmax_w", [size, label_size])
    softmax_b = tf.get_variable("softmax_b", [label_size])
    self.logits = logits = tf.matmul(output, softmax_w) + softmax_b
    loss = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, self.targets)
    self._cost = cost = tf.reduce_sum(loss) / batch_size
    # self._cost = cost = -tf.reduce_sum(tf.reshape(self.targets, [-1, 1])
    #                                    *tf.log(tf.clip_by_value(tf.log(tf.nn.softmax(logits)), 1e-10,1.0)))
    self._final_state = states[-1]
    if not is_training:
        return
    self._lr = tf.Variable(0.0, trainable=False)
    tvars = tf.trainable_variables()
    grads, _ = tf.clip_by_global_norm(tf.gradients(cost, tvars),
                                      config.max_grad_norm)
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(self.lr)
    self._train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, tvars))

def step(self, session, inputs, labels, is_training):
    if is_training:
        output_feeds = [self.cost, self._final_state, self._train_op]
    else:
        output_feeds = [self.cost]
    input_feeds = {
        self.input_data: inputs,
        self.targets: labels
    }
    cost, state, logits = session.run(output_feeds, input_feeds)
    return cost, state, logits
```

Comment: How exactly are you modeling the similarity here? What does your data look like?

Answer (score 0):

A small recommendation for you.

You can use two encoders(either RNN or CNN) one for each sentence, and then encoder these two sentence into two sentence embeddings. Once you have the two sentence vectors you just calculate the cosine similarity as the output. 1 if the two sentence have the same meaning and 0 if not for training. In inference you can input any two sentences and get the cosine similarity as the sentence semantic similarity.

Answer (score 0):

With RNN the assumption is that there are sequential relationships between the inputs. Concatenating two sentences implies to the network that they compose a single sequence, but this isn't the case. For a comparison between two sentences, each should be represented individually.